# Twitter bootstrap - automatically avoid tooltip overlap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have multiple elements that are dynamically positioned and each of them has a tooltip. Sometimes the position of tooltips of 2 elements overlaps. Is it possible for tooltips to automatically occupy the next available empty placement slot (`top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`)?

Each tooltip would check if it would potentially overlap with existing tooltips & cycle through the remaining 3 placement slots.

Comment: Maybe, it's better to avoid multiple tooltips at a time. Just show one of them. Or this is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into an overlap problem. The solution is maybe not as you wanted almost 2 years ago, but here's the output sample:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MogST.jpg

The default tooltip position is top center. For the "alternate" tooltips (question mark on the image) I use this code:

```
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="%yourtitle%"
```